# Python programming for retriving false negative values

Tags: python, numpy

How to retrieve the false negative values which was taken from confusion matrix by using python:

```
Tn:27, FP=0, FN=7, TP=6
```

Any help would be appreciated:

```
idx = X[np.where(y_test != y_pred)[0]].sum(axis=1)

np.array(corpus)[idx] # I have tried this I could not able to get those.

idx=X[np.where(y_test != y_pred)[0]].sum(axis=1)
np.array(corpus)[idx]

Tp-6 TN-27 FP=0 FN=7
```

I want retrieve the false negative values. I am getting all false positive and false negative values from the above code, but I am trying to retrive only false negative values.

Comment: Could you give us a small set of example data to make this reproducible locally, or show us how your data is arranged currently?

Answer (score 0):

you can use boolean indexing to get the false negetive values

```py
## get boolean indexes for false negetive 
fn_ind = (y_pred==False) & (y_pred != y_test)
fn_rows = X[fn_ind]
```

Comment: sorry, miss read the question, I have update the answer now to get false negtaive values